# Sorting strings in order

Tags: arrays

I'd like to sort a list e.g. [stack, overflow, yeet, apple] to [aelpp ,ackst, eety, efloorvw]. I have my code for radix sorting numbers:

```
def countingsort(nums, place):
  n = len(nums)
  output = [0 for i in range(0,n)]
  
  freq = [0 for i in range(0,10)]
  
  for i in range(0,n):
    freq[(nums[i]//place)%10] += 1

  for i in range(1,10):
    freq[i] += freq[i - 1]      
  
  #Build the output array 
  for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
    output[freq[(nums[i]//place)%10] - 1] = nums[i] 
    freq[(nums[i]//place)%10] -= 1
  
  #List will now be the new array
  for i in range(0,n): 
    nums[i] = output[i]
```

I know I could do ord() and -ord('a') to modify the code into what I want, however I am unsure of where and how exactly I should implement it. Any hints on how I should approach?
Thank you!

EDIT as the radix is not altered.

Comment: Can you use a different sort to sort the letters themselves? Or should you only use the sort in here? I have my answer written but I'm wondering how much I can/I should change countingsort to properly take care of the letters

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

> but have no idea on how to sort each word's letters alphabetically. Any hints on how I should approach?

For sorting the word itself, you should do that before sorting the whole list - because in your example we sort them by their new version, `eety, efloorvw`, instead of the other way around (overflow < yeet).

So loop through the list first, sort each element, then sort the whole list.

As for using `ord()` or not - strings are comparable as they already are. :) BUT: we'll encounter a problem with all the 10's and division in your counting sort. So we need to fix it.

First: max. We want to find the longest thing, not the highest number.

Second: counting and indexing. We'll use ord in here to index 'a' as 0 through 'z' as 25... and we need a last bucket for strings that have no character at this place.

```
def radixsort(nums):
  n = len(nums)
  max = len(nums[0])
  
  #find max number in the array
  for i in nums:
    if max < len(i):
      max = len(i)
  
  #Counting sort is performed based on place. 
  #like ones place, tens place and so on.
  place = 1  # we'll use it to index string
  while max >= place: 
    countingsort(nums, place, max) # we need to know how many letters the longest string has
    place += 1

def countingsort(nums, place, max):
  n = len(nums)
  output = [0 for i in range(0,n)]
  
  #range of the letters is a-z and no character (giving 0-26 indexes) for each place considered.
  freq = [0 for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+2)]
  
  #count number of occurrences in freq array
  for i in range(0,n):
    if len(nums[i]) <= max-place:
      freq[26] += 1  # too short number, we need to put it in "empty character" bucket
    else:
      freq[ord(nums[i][max-place])-ord('a')] += 1
  
  #Change count[i] so that count[i] now contains actual 
  #position of this digit in output[] 
  for i in range(1,27):
    freq[i] += freq[i - 1]      
  
  #Build the output array 
  for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
    if len(nums[i]) <= max-place:
      index = 26
    else:
      index = ord(nums[i][max-place])-ord('a')
    output[freq[index] - 1] = nums[i]
    freq[index] -= 1
  
  #List will now be the new array
  for i in range(0,n): 
    nums[i] = output[i]
```

```
my_list = ['stack', 'overflow', 'yeet', 'apple']
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    sublist = list(my_list[i])  # convert string to list of characters - strings are immutable so we can't assign to their indexes
    radixsort(sublist)
    my_list[i] = "".join(sublist)  # convert sorted list back to string

radixsort(my_list)
```

[Omg, this took me way too long, I made stupid mistakes I needed to debug]

Comment: thanks for correction me please remove last line in your code as `my_list` is all ready sorted and `radixsort` take a list of `int` Object

Comment: @throwaway13 oof, this took me way too long to debug, even though I knew what I was aiming for (I used n instead of max and it didn't work, lol, I spent like 20 minutes trying to see what was wrong). The version now should work (if I copied the correct version, lol, I need to check it - edit: diff says only whitespace and comments differ, so it's good)

Comment: It's returning None when I run it. I printed some things to debug and at the end of my countingsort() it prints the sorted list, however ends the list with a None. Hmm I'll try to analyze the code!

Comment: @throwaway13 The code you posted in question doesn't print anything either. The change happens in place, so `print(my_list)` shows the sorted thing

Answer (score -1):

Above logic you can implement in this way:

```
list1 = ['stack', 'overflow', 'yeet', 'apple'] 

print(sorted([''.join(sorted(i)) for i in list1]))
```

Comment: This is not a question about how the person can simplify the code... It's probably part of a homework and the question is only about the words.